# How to call Sub in Class B from another Sub in Class A

Tags: excel, vba

I am searching for a sample piece of VBA coding where a Sub in Class B is called from a Sub in Class A where all precautions are included to prevent a NullReferenceException at the moment of the call. I have read some  articles about this item but for me as starter with Visual Studio VBA Excel it's quite hard to understand and with a sample coding I can learn how it works. Can someone please help me.

### This is my base-coding:

- Public Class AAA
- Public Sub AAASub()
- ```
     Call BBB.BBBSub()
  ```
- End Sub
- End Class
- 
- 
- Public Class BBB
- Public Sub BBBSub()
- ```
     MsgBox("BBBSub started")
  ```
- End Sub
- End Class

I have read some articles about this issue and I hope to receive a sample VBA code from which I can learn how to do this properly.

Comment: How the  post is written you just have to set the Attribute `VB_PredeclaredId = True` and you will be able to do what you want. What's the background of the question.? Sounds not a good idea to do somehting like that, at least IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of handling Class Modules in VBA is e.g.

```
' **************************************************************
'  Module:  mdlStart  Type = common module
' **************************************************************

Option Explicit
    
Public Sub DoMyClass()
    Dim c1 As New cls1
    c1.AAASub
End Sub



' **************************************************************
'  Module:  cls1  Type = class
' **************************************************************

Option Explicit
    
Public Sub AAASub()
    Dim c2 As New cls2
    c2.BBBSub
End Sub


' **************************************************************
'  Module:  cls2  Type = class
' **************************************************************

Option Explicit
    
Public Sub BBBSub()
    MsgBox ("BBBSub started")
End Sub
```

But if you want something similar to VB.Net shared or C# static go with @Storax advice of VB_PredeclaredId.
But you can use common modules in VBA so what is the need for?

Comment: Thank you  all for your help. I have decided before I go on re-building my Excel macro's to add-in's for Excel in Visual Studio, I first  start reading and learning more about the basic elements of the VBA language. I come against too many issues that take lots of time. In the time between I will try to compile my Excel macro's so that they will better perform. This question can be closed for me.